# is there jquery-ui-vsdoc.js like jquery-vsdoc.js for Visual Studio?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying the Jquery-ui library on Visual Studio 2010. And I wonder whether `jquery-ui-vsdoc.js` is available like `jquery-vsdoc.js` for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jay kimble](http://theruntime.com/blogs/jaykimble/archive/2009/07/20/jquery-ui-visual-studio-intellisense-vsdoc-file.aspx) tried to have a go at this but I think he didn't finish his project. I think this was to do with not being enough demand for such thing.

However [the incomplete project is present](http://theruntime.com/blogs/images/theruntime_com/blogs/jaykimble/WindowsLiveWriter/jQueryUIvisualstudiointellisensevsdocfil_98FB/jquery-ui-vsdoc_1.js) and if you are very keen on this maybe you can finish it. (It's not very hard to work out how to finish it, that is why I suggest you looking at this.)

Also if you want to read more in depth you can have a look at [how vsdoc files can be developed](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx).